I was scamed by Exopip
I got a call from Cypertrack and they say that they can help me but they need access to my wallet to close them down. The wallets are empty, is there any risk to give them this access?
Are they releable ?
Regards Jon


[Cypertrack] need access to my wallet to close [Exopip] down

That looks like nonsense to me. I would assume they are softening you up for subsequent manipulation.
Victims of scams are very often regarded as  targets by fake recovery agents.

The wallets are empty,

Wallets with a zero "balance" still contain private keys. Anyone with access to the wallet can copy those keys and later use them to steal money you later add to that wallet, even after you have changed the wallet's password.
